# Setup WebStorm for Elixir (Project SDK is not defined)

Tags: elixir, webstorm

I've been trying to setup WebStorm to work with Elixir and I'm getting a `Project SDK is not defined` message.

[image]

This is what I have:

```
$ elixir -v
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.0] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [ds:8:8:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Elixir 1.5.1
```

I also have Elixir's plugin for WebStorm, version: 5.1.0

I first had Elixir installed with brew but read people where having this problem with brew installs. Now I just tried installing it with MacPorts but nothing changed.

Extra info:

```
$ which elixir
/opt/local/bin/elixir

$ which mix
/opt/local/bin/mix
```

And this is how I'm trying to setup `Elixir External Tools`:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong?

**P.S.: I saw a similar SO question answered here, but couldn't fix the problem with the information there, nor the followup issues on github.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In last input (Elixir SDK path) you have to point to elixir installation folder. Since plugin have to find other files, not just elixir executable.

Edit: In my case, installed with Homebrew, the folder was:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set first Erlang path and then Elixir path.

Find path you can by this:

```
find / -type d -name "*erlang*"

=> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/erlang

find / -type d -name "*elixir*"

=> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/elixir
```

And then in setup set Erlang and Elixir paths with versions, for example:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/erlang/25.2
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/elixir/14.3.2
```

[image]
[image]

And then set Elixir SDK:

[image]